# http://localhost:4200/assets/product.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to read a json file data through a service.I have created the file in the assets folder named product.json.
But on running the code it returns "http://localhost:4200/assets/product.json 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

here is my service file code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProductDataService {
    headers:Headers;
    options:RequestOptions;
//url:string="/localservice/product.json";
url:string = "assets/product.json"
  constructor(private _http:Http) { 
      this.headers = new Headers({'Content-type':'application/json','Accept':'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9'});
      this.options  =new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers})
  }


  getAllProduct(){
    return this._http.get('../assets/product.json',this.options)
    .map((res:Response)=>res.json());
  }
}
```

I have tried using  "assets/product.json","../assets/product.json" as path

porduct.component.ts:

```
export class ProductComponent {

    allProduct:Product[]=[];
    constructor(private _data:ProductDataService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
      /* this._data.getAllProduct().subscribe(
        (data:Product[])=>{
          this.allProduct=data;
        }
      ); */
    }
    onClick(value:string){
  if(value!=''){
  this.allProduct=this.allProduct.filter(res=>res.pname.startsWith(value));
  }
  else{
    this._data.getAllProduct().subscribe(
        (data:Product[])=>{
          this.allProduct=data;
        }
      );
    }
  }

}
```

angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "new-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

please tell me where is the problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your `assets` folder it should be inside `src` and `cli-config` should have the `assets` folder in the `includes` property

Comment: Could you please post the .angular-cli file also?

Comment: yes assets is inside src

Comment: Do you have  `<base href="/">` in index.html file?

Comment: yes <base href="/"> is there

Comment: Did you double check that the json file is called exactly product.json (exactly the same case, no capital letter)? And the url should be /assets/product.json (leading slash) so that is works whatever the current page is

Comment: i just ran another project made by someone else doing the same thing. IT RUNS!!!. But its based on angular v5 mine is 4.2. will that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

use path like `this._http.get('assets/product.json',this.options)` instead of `this._http.get('../assets/product.json',this.options)`

```
getAllProduct() {
    return this._http.get('assets/product.json', this.options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: @mohittyagi can you share the file structure of project in this question ?

Comment: product structure is the same as when you create a new angular project

Answer (score 0):

try code like below

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProductDataService {
private data: any;

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getData(){
   this.http.get('assets/data/products.json')
   .map((res) => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
   }, (rej) => {
          console.error("Could not load local data",rej)
   });
 }
}
```

change `../assets/data/products.json` to `assets/data/products.json`